# RewriteRule for same name

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a file called

details.php

and I tried to put in htaccess the following line

```
RewriteRule ^details/(.+)/(.+)$ /details.php?id=$1&name=$2 [NC]
```

and it doesn't works with the same name which is currently targeted

UPDATE 1:

Problem solved with by adding -MultiViews

Options +FollowSymLinks **-MultiViews**

Comment: try RewriteRule ^/details/(.+)/(.+)$ /details.php?id=$1&name=$2 [NC]

Comment: opsi, ** bold :P I tried to draw attention to the word "details"

Comment: @JohnStrave Why does "-MultiViews" solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

remove the "**"'s. "*" is a special character meaning "zero or more of the previous character". That there is two in a row of them acouple of places in your regular expression is highly irregular, if not incorrect. If indeed you have a file named `details.php`, you don't need them either.

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

```
RewriteRule ^details/([0-9]+)/(\w+)/?$ /details.php?id=$1&name=$2 [NC,L]
```

Where:

**id** = limits the id only to numbers 
**name** = limits the name only to words+nums

Comment: nop..still the same... Notice: Undefined index: id in public_html/details.php on line 7 Notice: Undefined index: name in public_html/details.php on line 8

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I had an issue where I required a url rewrite but could not figure out why it was failing. Then I stumbled across this thread and it fixed my problem.

The issue is, Multiviews is enable by default on my hosting provider. [This Page](http://blog.razuna.com/2008/03/27/apache-htaccess-and-directive-multiviews/) explains in detail why this simply does not mesh with RewriteRules well. I added -Multiviews to this to fix my problem:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /devpath/SampleCustomerName/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

If I wanted to navigate to /devpath/SampleCustomerName/about while about.php resided in that folder, I would receive a 404 error.

With +Multiviews

> “It can choose the best representation of a resource based on the browser-supplied preferences for media type, languages, character set and encoding. It also implements a couple of features to give more intelligent handling of requests from browsers that send incomplete negotiation information.”.
>   "Point is that the Multiviews directive interefered with our rewrite rule. Thus the solution to get our rewrite rule to work properly was to add a custom directive to the host in question without the Mutliviews option."